# Isapi filter not working on IIS 7 (which did work on IIS 6)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I have an Isapi dll which performs some basic URL rewriting. It works fine on II6. However, now my dev machine has been upgraded to Windows 7, I cannot get it to work under IIS 7

Is there anything special that needs to be done to get this to work?

The website is running the Classic ASP pipeline app pool (although I have tried both)

Any suggestions on how to get this resolved?

thanks a lot

p.s rewriting it as a module/handler is not an option. I only want to know how to get the existing dll to work on IIS 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved. I am running the 64 bit version of Windows 7 so needed to change one of the options on the app pool "Allow 32-bit applications"